# Placing Forums within Categories (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the process of creating a forum using Ruby on Rails (I'm pretty new at this) and have managed to get myself utterly stuck.

**Version Ruby on Rails 4.0 **

A forum software can have many Categories, and within these Categories you can have multiple forums.

The main page would look similar to this:

Category 1

- Forum 1
- Forum 2

Category 2

- Forum 3
- Forum 4
- Forum 5

When you create a forum, you should have a drop down menu that allows you to select which category you wish to place it in.

At first I created two different scaffolds- One for Categories and one for Forums. I used a foreign key to connect the two. I do not know if this is the best method, but I could not get them to interact at all. I ended up screwing up my code so badly I have very little to show for it.

I tried using [Adding Sub-categories in Rails4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237745/adding-sub-categories-in-rails4) and [categories and sub-categories model rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197897/categories-and-sub-categories-model-rails?rq=1) for solutions but both ended up causing errors.

Here is some of my code. It's not much, but maybe you can tell me where to even begin. If there is a better way of doing this (not using two tables), let me know. I would love to hear the best possible way of doing this **without using gems**

WARNING: my code is an utter mess.

**Migration**

```
    class AddForeignToForums < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :forums, :category_id, :integer
      end
    end
```

**Forum Controller** (I know I am missing something that will allow me to connect to the Category, I just don't know what)

class ForumsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_forum, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
  # GET function. view/forums/index.html.erb
  def index
    @forums = Forum.all
  end

  # GET /forums/1. view/forums/show.html.erb
  def show
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /forums/new. view/forums/new.html.erb
  # Be able to list all the Categories. 
  def new
    @forum = Forum.new
    @categories = Category.all

  end

  # GET /forums/1/edit
  # Be able to list all the categories. 
  def edit
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # POST /forums
  # Allows the creation of a new forum
  # Lindsey note: how to save category_idea. Assign to category.
  def create
    @forum = Forum.new(forum_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @forum.save
        @forum = Forum.new(:name => params[:forum][:name], 
        :category_id => params[:forum][:category_id])  

        format.html { redirect_to @forum, notice: 'Forum was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @forum }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @forum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /forums/1
  # Allows the update of forums.
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @forum.update(forum_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @forum, notice: 'Forum was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @forum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /forums/1
  def destroy
    @forum.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to forums_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_forum
      @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def forum_params
      params.require(:forum).permit(:name, :description, :category_id)
    end
end
```

**Forum Model**

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Category Model**

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :forums, :dependent => :destroy, 
 end
```

**Category Index.html.erb**

```
  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to category.name, category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to ' (Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to '| Destroy)', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>

      <% category.forums.each do |forum| %>
        <tr>
          <td><li><%= link_to forum.name, forum %></li></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**Forum _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@forum) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>

<%= f.label :category_id %><br />
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]} %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a table for forums, a table for categories, and a join table that includes a forum_id and category_id - name this forum_categories

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :forum_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :forum_categories

end
```

And, with categories, you'll do the reverse

```
class Categories < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :forum_categories
  has_many :forums, :through => :forum_categories

end
```

For adding categories in the view, you can use checkboxes or a multiple select box.  The name of this input will be either

```
f.check_box 'category_ids[]'
```

or

```
f.select 'category_ids[]'
```

This will submit a param in an array format that will allow you to update the forum.category_ids with a simple

```
forum.create(params[:forum])
```

In your view, instead of @forums, you'll list category.forums

```
  <% category.forums.each do |forum| %>
    <%= forum.name %>
  <% end %>
```

Hopefully this will get you started.

EDIT

For a single category on Forum, you've done well.  Just a few smaller changes:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  # belongs_to :category - this can be removed
  has_many :forums # Do you want to delete the forums if the category is removed?  You don't need the classname option.

end
```

In the drop down - you'll do something like this...

```
f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
```

Comment: Would I still want a join table if the relationship is not many-to-many? This portion of my database has a relationship of one to many, as forums can only be assigned to one category.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood that.  You're fine with the category_id. I added a bit more to the answer.